# нулевая ширина абсолютно позиционированного div'а

Tags: html, css

всем доброго времени. нужна помощь. просьба не забрасывать тряпками. 
в общем есть у меня два блока div. и мне необходимо частично на одном, частично на втором разместить третий блок, чтобы он наложился на фон первого и второго блоков, для этого третий блок я позиционирую абсолютно. но в итоге в классе .main_places я получаю нулевую высоту и ширину равную ширине окна, а в классе .table_places я получаю нулевую ширину и нормальную высоту. как мне получить истинные размеры чтобы в дальнейшем я мог манипулировать блоком .main_places с помощью js и как сделать собственный background у данного блока?.

```css
.table_places{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}
.main_places{
    position: relative;

}
.places_row {
    margin: 0 32%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.place_section {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
.table_places:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.place-name {
    text-align: left;

}
.place-name span {
    font-family: "Segoe WP N";
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main_places">
        <div class="table_places">
            <div class="places_row">
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Azheekal.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Humpi.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class="background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Kovalam.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Munnar.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class="background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Ooty.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="places_row">
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Azheekal.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Humpi.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class="background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Kovalam.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class=" background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Munnar.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="place_section">
                    <div class="background_section_image">
                        <img src="img/places/Ooty.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="place-name">
                        <span>Sites</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из вашего вопроса вообще непонятно что вам надо. Какой из этих блоков "первый", "второй" и "третий"? Тот, который у вас спозиционирован абсолютно - кто он? И зачем? А для манипуляций блоками через JS вам не нужны никакие загадочные "истинные размеры" - вы можете задать им любое поддерживаемое яваскриптом свойство даже если оно изначально не установлено. П.С. Собственный фон у .main_places вы можете задать через CSS-свойство `background` (какой вопрос - такой ответ, да).

Comment: Первый это верхний, второй это нижний, третий тот что между первым и вторым.код приведен для третьего блока.через background не выходит потому что нет ширины.как только вручную я задам ширину, то применяется и background.но я хочу уйти от фиксированной ширины, мне нужно чтобы она сама вычислялась в зависимости от контента внутри.

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос изображение для примера.это не то что я делаю, просто для наглядности.первый это верхний с картинкой, второй это блок под картинкой, а третий это тот что наложен на первый и второй блоки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил.
Вроде соответствует вашей ситуации.

```css
.papa {
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
}

.son {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.background1 {background:gold; min-height:100px;}

.background3 {background:coral; min-height:100px;}

.background2 {
  position:absolute;
  background:pink;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  transform:translate(-50%, -30px);
  column-count:3;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:5px;
  column-gap:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="papa">
  <div class="son background1">
   --- это верхний блок (картинка) ---
  </div>
  <div class="son background2">
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
    <div class="item">block</div>
  </div>
  <div class="son background3">
   --- это нижний блок ---
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не, это не то что я хотел

Comment: Поправил. Вроде соответствует вашей ситуации.